# I need to run Python 3 script using Java code

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have the following Java code snippet and it is working for Python 2  compatible scripts. However, I am not getting any output when I use Python 3 compatible script using Java.

```
String[] cmd = {
                python,
                file.getAbsolutePath(),
                };
String[] envCommand = {"source activate root"}; //My root environment is having python3, 

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = runtime.exec(cmd, envCommand);
readOutputFromPythonProcess(process);
```

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. See [ask], then provide a [mcve].

Comment: The second argument to `exec` is not a command, it's a list of environment variable strings (in the form of `{"VAR1=VALUE1", "VAR2=VALUE2"}`). You shoud use a copy of the current env and alter that, otherwise you'll end up with an empty environment.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using exec, be sure to set python as`"python3"` and also read error stream for any errors your script will give

Comment: I tried this and getting Exception occured while processing the python script - Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: What do you mean by processing?